# Javascript type conversion from string to object without Modifying the values

Tags: javascript, php, json, regex

I am having trouble converting string to object without modifying the value.

Here's the php code:

```
<?php foreach($customauto as $customautos)
{
$tempTags[] = $customautos->firstname;
}
?>

dump($tempTags);
```

So when I dump the value, i get the result as below.

```
string '["New Client","LIC CLIENT","TEST","valan","Mevis","xczx","dfgfd","test"]'
```

clearly it states that its a string.

In javascript function I use json_encode.

```
var availableTags = '<?php echo json_encode($tempTags); ?>';
```

I alert the variable to check for the variable value which i get as i want.

```
alert(availableTags);
```

And i get the value as below which is perfect.

```
["New Client","LIC CLIENT","TEST","valan","Mevis","xczx","dfgfd","test"]
```

So i tried using that variable for autocomplete. but it did not work.
So i alerted to check for type of the variable.

```
alert(typeof availableTags);
```

and i get the type as string.

So i used the JSON.parse function

```
alert(JSON.parse(availableTags));
```

and it gets converted to object but the brackets and double quotes are ommited

```
New Client,LIC CLIENT,TEST,valan,Mevis,xczx,dfgfd,test
```

So how can i keep the brackets and the double quotes intact and convert string to object.

Comment: What does `dump` do? Its an array, that function is converting it to a string.

Comment: I use codeigniter. so i have created a dump function which displays the type and value of the variable.

Comment: `var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($tempTags); ?>;` remove the quotes

Comment: I removed it now its not alerting the variable;

Comment: The brackets and quotes denote a JSON array of string values, so when parsed to a JSON object they will get 'removed'. Perhaps you can be clearer re what you are expecting in a parsed object.

Comment: On the Javascript side, do not use `alert` but rather `console.log` (and open the console in your web browser), it will give you a much clearer idea of what the variable contains.

Comment: i want the result as  ["xyz", "abc ",...]   which i get but in string type but i want it in object type, but when i use    JSON.parse(availableTags); the values are changed to just   xyz,abc  with the quotes and bracket omitted

Answer (score 0):

All the brackets and double quotes are NOT omitted.

The `alert` window can't show you the object as JSON (you can use `console.log()` instead).

`availableTags = JSON.parse(availableTags)` will do the job and will create an object so you can work with it :)